# Elastic search index for Ngram?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, n-gram

Say I have a sentence `This is a new city`

1. Does Elastic search create index for all possible permutation/combination of a word. For example for word "city", will it create the index "it","ty","ity", "cit" etc ?
2. Are these indexes created at document storage time or at run time ?
3. Are these indexes kept in memory or in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. That depends on your [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html). By default Elasticsearch uses [Standant Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) which `divides text into terms on word boundaries, as defined by the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm.` That means your sentence will be tokenized as `this, is, a, new, city`. You can create custom tokenizer if you like to.
2. Documents are indexed when you put them to Elasticsearch.
3. The data is kept in file system: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-dive-into-elasticsearch-storage

Here is a blog post about internals: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up

Comment: One question on point 1. Will elastic search not search the word `city` when i enter partial word `it` by default? Do i need to create the custom tokenizer to create index on possible anagram of each word  ?

Comment: It changes based on your query type. For such a match you can use `wildcard` query with `*it*`. Refer to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html.

Comment: When you say `For such a match you can use ..`  Are you asking end user to use wildcard ? I thought ES automatically does it ?

Comment: ES has a lot of search options. Much of them works on terms `this, is, a, new, city` in your case. Of course you can use custom tokenizer to also index `it` as a term. Then you can use normal queries other then `wildcard`.

Comment: take an example of google search. Even if i enter `cty` instead of `city` it will search city. Does google or any other similar engine create index of all possible anagrams of words in document?

Comment: If you want "Did you mean?" like functionality you can check: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html